# Animated object keeps moving past last keyframe; why?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm animating a flying drone quadcopter, moving the quadcopter around the scene, adding, editing and deleting keyframes in the process. The issue is that suddenly instead of coming to a stop at the last keyframe, the quadcopter stays in motion, moving at the same vector as the last keyframe, apparently sailing onward to infinity. Why?

I have a noise modifier applied to the X,Y,& Z axes to simulate mild instability; would this have anything to do with it? Thanks. Blender 3.2.2, Windows 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it has. As you can see in the graph editor, if you add noise, Blender adds noise to "infinity".

[image]

But as you can see too, you can restrict the frame range there:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's it. Thank you!

Comment: glad i could help